# MySQL Multiple Simultaneous Queries From The Same Connection

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run multiple queries on a MySQL server at the same time from PHP with the same database connection. I have run the SQL statement on the server itself but the response is as expected. I'm getting no SQL exceptions but just no SQL query response at all (the result is FALSE).

Is this because you can't query when another query is already active on the same connection?

The code loads data from the database table with people's names and last paid date information. This is displayed in a form and then the user can select members to update payments for. Then, the part I'm stuck on is the second query where the selected names are trying to find family_id for families.

Code snippet:

```
mysql_select_db($database_W3OITesting, $W3OITesting);
$yearnow = date("Y",strtotime('+1 year')).'-12-31';
$yearrecent = date("Y",strtotime('-1 year')).'-12-31';
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT DISTINCT lname, fname, suffix, fcccall, members.member_id, MaxDateTime " .
"FROM members " .
"INNER JOIN " .
    "(SELECT paid.member_id, MAX(paid.year) AS MaxDateTime " .
    "FROM paid " .
    "GROUP BY paid.member_id) groupedpaid ".
    "ON members.member_id = groupedpaid.member_id " .
"Where (MaxDateTime < '$yearnow') AND ".
"(MaxDateTime >= '$yearrecent')" .
"ORDER BY lname, fname, suffix, fcccall";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $W3OITesting) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);

 //if a post is received handle it here
 function getPostArray($array){
 foreach ($array as $key => $value){
    //search here for if this member is part of a family
    //if not part of a family just update the payment
    //record for the member with the value
    try {
        $query_Recordset3 = "SELECT lname, fname, suffix,                 `members`.member_id , `family`.member_id " .
             "FROM members, family " .
             "WHERE (`members`.member_id = `family`.member_id " .
             "AND `members`.member_id = $key)";
        echo $query_Recordset3. "<br>";
        $Recordset3 = mysql_query($query_Recordset3, $W3OITesting);
        $row_Recordset3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset3);
        $totalRows_Recordset3 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset3);
        echo $totalRows_Recordset3 . "<br>";
        echo "$key => $value";
        if($totalRows_Recordset3==FALSE) {//Recordset3 is always FALSE
          echo " Error - " . $row_Recordset3['lname'];
        }
        if($totalRows_Recordset3!=0) {
          echo " - A Family";
         } else { 
          echo " - Individual";
         }
        echo "<br>";
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
     {
      echo "Exception: $e";
      die();
     }
    if(is_array($value)){ //If $value is an array, get it also
        getPostArray($value);
    }  
}
```

}

Comment: How were you expecting the Exceptions to be thrown in your deprecated source code?

Comment: So, in short, there is nothing simultaneous about your requests. And the world moved on to `mysqli` and `PDO` thus deprecating the code you are showing above (that doesn't do what you think it does)

Comment: Good catch. Unfortunately this is an older server with 5.4 PHP. I'm so used to using exceptions now I didn't check if the older server had it. Bad assumption.